# Не проигрывается mp3 через pyglet

Tags: python-3.x, mp3

Хочу проиграть музыку через python с помощью библиотеки ***pyglet***. mp3 лежит там же, где и исходник.
Когда я ввёл **код**:

`import pyglet
song = pyglet.media.load('kissvk.com-Wiz Khalifa-No Limit -Sencit Remix-.mp3', streaming=False)
song.play()
pyglet.app.run()`

То выходит **ошибка**:

```
wave.Error: file does not start with RIFF id
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
pyglet.media.codecs.wave.WAVEDecodeException: file does not start with RIFF id
```

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил воспользоваться другой библиотекой:

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("Catfish.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
stop_the_alarm = input()
if stop_the_alarm.isprintable():
pygame.mixer.music.stop()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    time.sleep(1)
```